# Wrong mappings when copying from PDF with \pdfgentounicode with newtx

Tags: unicode, times, newtx

It seems that `newtx` is nowadays the best option for Times font, and I wanted to test it with respect to Croatian specifics, but also with respect to some common math symbols, and copying the content from generated PDF.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}


\begin{document}

a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Đ Č Ć Ž

\bfseries
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Đ Č Ć Ž

\sffamily
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Đ Č Ć Ž

\ttfamily
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Đ Č Ć Ž

\[
  x \ne \neq y \quad
  x \le \leq \leqslant y \quad
  x \ge \geq \geqslant y
\]

\[
  x \coloneq \coloneqq y \quad
  y \eqcolon \eqqcolon x
\]

\end{document}
```

Opening the generated PDF in the latest Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, and copying the content into Unicode-friendly editor, I get this:

```
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Ð Č Ć Ž
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Ð Č Ć Ž
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Ð Č Ć Ž
a b c d e š đ č ć ž Š Ð Č Ć Ž
x ,, y x ≤≤6 y x ≥≥> y
x BB y y CC x
```

[image: Hex dump]

Found issues:

- I expected both `\ne` and `\neq` to be mapped to `U+2260`, but they are mapped to `U+002C` (regular comma).
- Both `\le` (`\ge`) and `\leq` (`\le`) are mapped correctly, but slanted variants are not - they should be mapped to `U+2A7D` (`U+2A7E`).
- Both `\coloneq` (`\coloneqq`) and `\eqcolon` (`\eqqcolon`) are not mapped correctly (to `U+2254` and `U+2255`), but to regular `B` and `C`.
- Although it looks like `đ` and `Đ` are copied correctly, they are not. `đ` is mapped to `U+0111` while `Đ` is mapped to `U+00D0` (not an lowercase-uppercase pair). Considering these two pairs:

  - U+00D0 Ð   c3 90   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH
  - U+00F0 ð   c3 b0   LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH
  - U+0110 Đ   c4 90   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE
  - U+0111 đ   c4 91   LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE

... I would say that `c3*`s are used in Icelandic language, while the latter two `c4*`s correspond to Croatian language. I also checked my source code, and hereby I confirm that my `đ` and `Đ` from the keyboard ended as `c4*`s encoding the source file in UTF-8.

Questions:

- `\ne` and `\neq`: Can someone explain why the mapping is wrong, and can that be improved so they are both correctly mapped?
- slanted variants: Can someone explain why the mapping is wrong, and can that be improved so they are correctly mapped?
- `\coloneq` and others: Can someone explain why the mapping is wrong, and can that be improved so they are correctly mapped?
- `đ` and `Đ`: Can someone explain why the mapping is wrong, and can that be improved so they are correctly mapped?

I am very keen to contribute for the improvements for all issues.

Kind regards, Ivan

EDIT: The question about `đ` and `Đ` is related to T1 font encoding, not the `newtx`, as explained in comments below.

Comment: Curiously enough, if I copy from a different PDF viewer (Skim, in my case), I get the correct glyphs, with or without `glyphtounicode` for the text part. Symbols are only partially recognized. With `glyphtounicode` I get all the text glyphs correct on Adobe Acrobat Reader. The fact that Ð is incorrectly mapped to ETH is kind of expected, as the T1 encoding doesn't have two different glyphs for the D with stroke and the ETH.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I dug into T1-specific definition files in my MiKTeX and found these: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D0}{\DH}`, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F0}{\dh}`, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0110}{\DJ}`, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0111}{\dj}`, `\DeclareTextSymbol{\DH}{T1}{208}`, `\DeclareTextSymbol{\DJ}{T1}{208}`, `\DeclareTextSymbol{\dh}{T1}{240}`, `\DeclareTextSymbol{\dj}{T1}{158}`. As you wrote, `\DJ` and `\DH` point to the same slot (208) and that causes experienced behavior. How can I "check" what all slots contain?

Comment: Do `pdflatex nfssfont` from the terminal and hit return at the prompts until you get `*`. Then type `\table\bye` and the PDF file will show the full table for a T1 encoded font.

Comment: OK, I see that table is actually given in encguide. So, the idea of having correctly paired mappings for `đ` and `Đ` ("with strokes") is not feasible for T1, actually for non-Unicode based TeX system.

Comment: I have read encguide thoroughly on this matter since yesterday, and things are much clearer to me now. (The issue about `Đ` is explained very well, I should have read that way before.)

I have even tried changing `/Eth` to `/Dcroat` in `lm-ec.enc` and tested new MWE using `lmodern` and `ð Ð đ Đ`; the outcome of copying the content from PDF was expected - everything was correct except Eth. I suppose all slots must be mapped uniquely to only one glyph (name), and `/Eth` was the decision (some history here http://www.tug.org/fontname/ec.enc)?

Comment: Instead of changing core `*.enc` files, is there any way of telling something like "let the slot 208 be `/Dcroat`" in the preamble?

Comment: Hi egreg. I thought of using `\pdfmapfile` or something similar, but having local modified copy of encoding file in the build folder, next to the source code (e.g modified `lm-ec.enc`, and any other respective T1 (EC) encoding files for the used fonts) gives the wanted behavior. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glyphtounicode.tex contains a lot declarations to map glyph names to unicode points. But it is not complete. To get e.g. the `\ne` to copy as ≠  add a suitable `\pdfglyphtounicode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\pdfglyphtounicode{nequal}{2260}

\begin{document}
$\ne$
\end{document}
```

(I found the `nequal` by looking in the txsyc.pfb).

Comment: Thanks! I guess that adding such definitions in `newtx` itself (or other fonts it is compound of) would be even better than defining it locally, right?