# Locally and one-slot-oriented font encoding definition change

Tags: symbols, unicode, font-encodings, copy-paste, mapping

Related to "Ð vs Đ": [Wrong mappings when copying from PDF with \pdfgentounicode with newtx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477433/wrong-mappings-when-copying-from-pdf-with-pdfgentounicode-with-newtx).

*I have even tried changing `/Eth` to `/Dcroat` in `lm-ec.enc` and tested new MWE using `lmodern` and ð Ð đ Đ; the outcome of copying the content from PDF was expected - everything was correct except Eth.*

*I thought of using `\pdfmapfile` or something similar, but having local modified copy of encoding file in the build folder, next to the source code (e.g. modified `lm-ec.enc`, and any other respective T1 (EC) encoding files for the used fonts) gives the wanted behavior.*

Instead of changing whole core font encoding definition files for used fonts (e.g. `lm-ec.enc`) or using their local copy with such change, is there any way of telling something like:

- *let the current font's slot 208 be `/Dcroat`*
- *let the slot 208 for all fonts be `/Dcroat`*

in the preamble **without redefining all other slots** (e.g. within `/enclmec[...] def`)?

EDIT:

I want to get `/Dcroat` out of this MWE on copy/paste action (not `/Eth`), redefining only one slot in the font encoding definition file(s): 208 - as both Icelandic "Eth" (`\DH`) and Croatian "D with stroke" (`\DJ`) are mapped to it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

Đ % Croatian

% I understand that mapping of Icelandic Eth would also be affected with such change, have no problem with that

\end{document}
```

EDIT2:
I am aware that redefining `glyphtounicode`'s `\pdfglyphtounicode{Eth}{00D0}` to `\pdfglyphtounicode{Eth}{0110}` would produce the same, but my intention is to intervene "one step earlier".

Comment: I have no idea what you want and what your problem is.

Comment: Well you can't intervene a step earlier. The pfb uses the name /Eth and this what pdflatex sees. And there is no /Dcroat in the pfb so you can't reencode it.

Comment: I think I can. Making a copy of `lm-ec.enc` in my local folder, and changing `/Eth` to `/Dcroat` (in line 216) works. My question is about doing the same without changing core files and without using local modifications - but "preamble-only" & redefining only one slot.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I should have checked the afm. If the glyph is there you can reencode them, but you will have to create a local copy of lm-ec.enc. Called it e.g. lm-ec-dcroat.enc. Change the glyph and change also at the start the encoding name e.g. to `/enclmecDcroat`. Then you can call in the document `\pdfmapline{=ec-lmr10 LMRoman10-Regular " enclmecDcroat ReEncodeFont " <lm-ec-dcroat.enc <lmr10.pfb}`.

Comment: Although the `\pdfmapline...` is there in the document, it still requires a whole modified file (containing only one change compared to the original). I expected there is a concise one-slot-oriented one-liner, but now I guess there is no such? (Quick check of "The pdfTeX user manual" did not help.) On the other hand, what does extra `\pdfmapline...` bring to user if local modified copy seems to be enough?

Comment: I would never change lm-ec.enc locally but always create a file with a new name if the content is different for the same reason for which I would never change article.cls locally.

Comment: "a copy of `lm-ec.enc` in my local folder" denotes a copy of core `lm-ec.enc` placed in the same folder as my root .tex file (and modified, of course). I do not fool around with the core files.

Comment: I would never create a changed copy of article.cls in my local folder. And if you ask next time a question about encodings I don't want to have to remember that the lm-ec.enc you load there is perhaps different to mine. Whatever you do you will have to ensure that no log-file that you post in a question or an issue ever use such a locally changed file.

Comment: I understand, good point! Let's conclude: there is no concise one-slot-oriented one-liner to modify the font encoding definition?

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a shortcoming of the T1 encoding, that has a single glyph for representing both `\DH` (ETH) and `\DJ` (D WITH STROKE). Unfortunately, the encoding was defined earlier than modern technology based on Unicode was available.

You can fix the issue more simply than by changing encoding files:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\pdfglyphtounicode{Eth}{0110}

\begin{document}

Đ % Croatian

\end{document}
```

Having both characters seems much more complicated, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks! Having both characters is not needed (Icelandic is out of my scope). On the other hand, I was aware of the solution you proposed (see EDIT2) and its drawback: `/Eth` is mentioned deeply within PDF, not `/Dcroat` (copy/paste action works as needed, of course). The question was about changing font encoding definition, not PDF `/ToUnicode` mapping - not sure if I should mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your question, but:

It’s already said that fonts that the `T1 encoding` doesn’t support `Dcroat` character. You can get this character if you change the `.enc` file, but this is not recommended.

Recently I created the [cmsrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmsrb) package. The purpose of this package is to fix standard encodings to support the Serbo-Croatian language characteristics, such as `Dcroat` instead `Eth`, Cyrillic letter `J` instead of Latin in `T2A` encoding, or support for the Macedonian letters that are not presented in the Cyrillic encodings, etc.

Therefore, the encodings are modified, so the `T1` supports the `Dcroat`, and `TS1` supports `Eth`, so you can easily get the both characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmsrb}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\DJ                         % Dcroat
\UseTextSymbol{TS1}{\DH}    % Eth
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there are no other fonts that support the `Dcroat` character (as far as I know).