# Which mappings are used if glyphtounicode/pdfgentounicode are not used

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, mapping, font-map

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\input{glyphtounicode} % *
\pdfgentounicode=1     % **


\begin{document}

A B C Č Ć D DŽ Đ \dots

\end{document}
```

Copy/Paste from Adobe Reader gives `A(0x41) B(0x42) C(0x43) Č(0xC48C) Ć(0xC486) D(0x44) DŽ(0x44 0xC5BD) Ð(0xC390) .(0x2E) .(0x2E) .(0x2E)` (UTF-8).

I am aware of the shortcomings of T1 in this MWE:

- not having separate slots for `ETH` and `D WITH STROKE`, hence I get `ETH` (`0xC390`): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569460/115879
- not having special slots for Croatian digraphs, hence they must be typeset as two separate characters (they are actually entered that way in the source code, using `Ǆ` and others yields an error)
- not having a special slot for the ellipsis, hence I get `FULL STOP` three times.

Which mappings (refer to the files in the distribution/package, please) will be used when:

1. `*` is commented
2. `**` is commented
3. both `*` and `**` are commented?

EDIT. Based on David Carlisle's comment, I change the question a bit: Can someone tell what happened e.g. five years ago when `glyphtounicode` was not input automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: the most recent pdflatex releases input glyphtounicode automatically, you can use Ǆ in the source code if you add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01C4}{DŽ}` or maybe `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01C4}{D\kern-.1emŽ}` I'm not sure how it is supposed to look?

Comment: No special kerning for all 9 variants (three letters with uppercase, titlecase and lowercase) are needed. Is `t1enc.dfu` somewhere officially versioned - I would like to propose such 9 definitions to be included (just as other special Unicode cases listed there)?

Comment: I can add them (probably) can you make an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues listing which ones you'd want?

Comment: without the mapping then (depending a bit on the pdf reader) you'd just get the numeric values from the T1 encoding interpreted (wrongly) as UTF-8 or latin-1 or whatever you were copying to (I think) (you don't need to go back 5 years, just before 2021-01-21 looking at the change log)

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Beside this: You could test that with an overleaf account, it allows you to use tex system of various ages.

Comment: A friend asked me how to successfully copy/paste Croatian specific letters (he did not use glyphtounicode, and obviously did not have up-to-date distribution), so I wanted to give him a detailed explanation what happened.

Comment: A proposal: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/723